# ASP .Net MVC | How to add subviews in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, because of I dont know how to write subview in user dashboard.

Example:

I have a dashboard for logged users and there is path Dashboard/Profile.
Dashboard -controller, Profile - view.
In Profile view I wouldlike to create sections/subviews (I dont know how it is called) named Overview, personal data, change password.

I have a menu on left and I want to get that if I will click "personal data", it will be loaded content with personal datas in the container on the right - but with no reloading all page. 
The same situation with clicking "change password", I want to show content of "change password" view on right side - without reloading.

How can I get it ? Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need javascript and ajax to dynamically load content into the view without refreshing the page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean I need to create ActionResults methods with actions what I need? and separate partial views for changing password, personal data and overview ? I am right ?

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to say popup a dialog displaying a form to change the users password, you would use say `$(someElement)load('@Url.Action(...)')` that calls a server method which returns a partial view of your 'ResetPasswordForm' and inserts it inside `someElement`

Comment: Great :) 
Please tell me how it works , because of I cannot imagine it.
I click " personal data" and js script is executing, but if I need also to add some code in View in place where i want to display datas? or maybe only in menu with js scripts ?

Comment: Your question is far too broad to add an answer as it stands. Edit your question (or ask a new question) explaining what you trying to do, and the code you have tried, and indicate whats not working and what errors your getting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this is what you are looking for ?
[Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial)

Comment: Yes, but If I am not wrong, Partial views can be used if we dont want reloading page. I mean that partial views are included permanently to main view. I want to get that these "partial views" will be loaded only when I click proper button in menu.

Comment: As mentioned above. I suggest using websockets instead of using other techniques. Take a look at this - https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/ and also this post - https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/real-time-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 0):

I would look at returning partial views from controllers and AJAX get requests.

In your controller

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // do some stuff
        return PartialView();
    }    
}
```

In your js scripts

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Some/SomeAction',
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'html'
})
.success(function (result) {
    $("#container").html(result);
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
    alert("We are having trouble, please try again later");
});
```

Of course the best way to handle these things is with a front end framework like angular 2 or react.